# Drawing shape over a Video

Tags: c++, drawing, c++builder

I'm writing a basic video player program with C++Builder and the Microsoft Media Foundation API. I want to draw a shape over a video while the video is paused or in a draw mode. I tried GDI and GDI+. These APIs draw behind the video. I also tried Direct2D and Direct3D, but the result is the same.

How can I do this?

By the way, I tried OpenCV for C++ Builder, but with no success.

**EDIT:** This is my code for the Microsoft Media Foundation API:

```
void __fastcall TForm6::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    IMFPMediaPlayer *imfp = NULL;
    Panel1->Color = clRed;//(TColor)0x00D5D500;
    dc = GetDC(Panel2->Handle);
    HRESULT hres = MFPCreateMediaPlayer(L"E:\\xxx.mp4", TRUE, 0, imfpcall, 
    Panel2->Handle, &imfp);
    imfp->SetBorderColor(RGB(125,85,0));    
}
```

And this is my GDI drawing code:

```
void __fastcall TForm6::DrawL()
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    Panel2->Repaint();
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,2,RGB(255,130,0));
    ResetDCW(dc,devMode);
    SelectObject(dc,hPen);
    BeginPaint(this->Handle, &ps);
    MoveToEx(dc, Dot2->Left + 15, Dot2->Top + 15, NULL);
    LineTo(dc, Dot1->Left + 15, Dot1->Top + 15);
    EndPaint(this->Handle, &ps);

    BeginPaint(this->Handle, &ps);
    MoveToEx(dc, Dot3->Left + 15, Dot3->Top + 15, NULL);
    LineTo(dc, Dot2->Left + 15, Dot2->Top + 15);
    StrokePath(dc);
    EndPaint(this->Handle, &ps);
}
```

**EDIT:** Images

Before Playing Video Image

[image]

After Video Playing

[image]

Comment: You can't draw on a `TPanel`'s `HWND` from outside of the `TPanel`'s own `Paint()` method, and you should not be calling `BeginPaint()` outside of a `WM_PAINT` message. The only place you should ever draw on a `TForm`'s `HWND` is in the Form's `OnPaint` event. A better way to handle this is to place a `TShape` or `TPaintBox` or equivilent on top of the `TPanel` (as the video is drawn onto the `TPanel` itself).

Comment: Thank you Remy.But i can draw lines  with GDI on TPanel during video file don't loading.But don't be retain lines so move outside of screen or size changed window this lines erasing.I tried TShape but MFP write video to TShape.I adding two image before video playing and after video playing.

Comment: exactly. Any drawing you do on tje panel outside of the panel's `WM_PAINT` handler is not persistent. It can and will be redrawn many many times during its lifetime. It is just that the Media API is drawing after you, so it draws on top of your drawing.

Comment: Well.I tried catch WM_PAINT message and tried drawing process.But it unsuccess.In addition to,WM_PAINT message just occur when mouseover event on the panel!. And why MFP video write to over of TShape and it can't write to over of button?